# How to change numeric variable into categorical

Tags: r, vector, replace

im trying to change the "Wine" variable to a categorical variable

```
wine_df
wine_df$Wine
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [75] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[112] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[149] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

## create categories of A=1, B=2, C=3

```
wine <- cut(wine_df$Wine, breaks=c(1,2,3), labels=c("A", "B", "C"))

Error in cut.default(wine_df$Wine, breaks = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("A",  : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
```

but keep getting this error:

```
Error in cut.default(wine_df$Wine, breaks = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("A",  : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
```

anyone can support on the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cut` assigning `breaks` properly. Read `?cut`

```
cut(x, 0:3, c("a", "b", "c"))

#[1] a b b c c c
#Levels: a b c
```

Used @markus's data

```
x <- rep(1:3, 1:3)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `LETTERS` and extract the values accordingly

Input

```
x <- rep(1:3, 1:3)
```

Output

```
LETTERS[x]
#[1] "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

---

The point here is that we can use `x` to extract the values of another vector by position.

If the goal was to change 1 = x, 2 = y and 3 = z (or whatever) we can do

```
c("x", "y", "z")[x]
#[1] "x" "y" "y" "z" "z" "z"
```

Thanks to @zx8754 for the helpful comments.

Comment: Probably A, B, C is just an example, could be any string.

Comment: I did try that, didn't work out for me:

Comment: @zx8754 Good point. Though I tried to stick to the example given by OP. Will Delete/edit if this is not what they want. I wanted to illustrate how we can use `LETTERS`.

Comment: No need to delete, maybe point out, that it could be any string vector `c("A", "B", "C")[ x ]`

Answer (score 3):

One way to treat categorical variables in R is through *Factors*. From the help (`?factor`):

> The function `factor` is used to encode a vector as a factor (the terms
>   ‘category’ and ‘enumerated type’ are also used for factors). If
>   argument `ordered` is TRUE, the factor levels are assumed to be ordered.
>   For compatibility with S there is also a function `ordered`.

Like this you can assign arbitrary strings as factor levels:

```
levels <- factor(c("category a", "category b", "category c"))
rep(1:3, 2)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
levels[rep(1:3, 2)]
[1] category a category b category c category a category b category c
Levels: category a category b category c
```

And of course you can also just assign "A", "B" and "C" like that:

```
levels <- factor(c("A", "B", "C"))
rep(1:3, 2)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
levels[rep(1:3, 2)]
[1] A B C A B C
Levels: A B C
```